# How to have all the data from my meteor+cordova app stored in a common database?

Tags: android, mongodb, cordova, meteor, mlab

I've a meteorjs app which I'm making for android devices (mobile app) using cordova and it has a form for placing orders which, after submitting, the data should be shown in a common database where the moderators can check the data entries and edit/delete as required.I've been suggested to use mongohq/mongolab but I'm confused and wondering if those will be able to meet my requirements.

Here's my database code which inserts all the information of the form after submitting:

---

```
Template.shop.events({
    'click #submit':function(evt,tmpl){
        evt.preventDefault();
        var name = tmpl.find('.name').value;
        var email = tmpl.find('.email').value;
        var phone = tmpl.find('.mobile').value;
        var delivery=tmpl.find('.delivery').value;
        var apple=tmpl.find('.apple').value;
        var pear=tmpl.find('.pear').value;
        var pineapple=tmpl.find('.pineapple').value;;
        var address=tmpl.find('.address').value;;
        var date=new Date();

        Shop.insert({
            name:name,
            email:email,
            phone:phone,
            delivery:delivery,
            apple:apple,
            pear:pear,
            pineapple:pineapple,
            address:address,
            time:date.toLocaleDateString()+' at '+date.toLocaleTimeString() 
        });
        alert('Your form has been submitted!');
        Session.set('adding_cart', false);

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In short both your cordova version and your web version will use the same database.

**Longer Answer**

After checking the collection.allow on the client it will send a call to the server, which will check the collection.allow on the server and decide whether or not to insert in the shared database or not.  An application that uses Cordova will use the same database as your web version.

**Assumptions**

You don't have the packages `autopublish` or `insecure` in your app.